# Use dll win32 in linux platforms

Tags: linux, dll, wine

I want to use a DLL library for Win32 in Linux.

Can I use a library of Wine to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do that using [winelib](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib).
[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110507055055/http://www.linux.ie/articles/interviews/weigand.php) is an interview with Ulrich Weigand a prominent WINE developer:

> - I managed one to get WineLIB to use a windows dll for VQF playing.
>     Do you forsee people using WineLIB to write applications in Linux that need a closed source windows dll?
>     **Sure. IMO that's one of the main features of WineLib: you can use it to link native Windows DLLs into Linux apps.
>     I think there are lots of examples where this could be useful; think of ODBC drivers, video codecs, etc.
>     (That's why I recently added support for executing even 16-bit DLLs inside WineLib apps, because Win95 drivers tend to thunk down to 16-bit ...)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use win32 dll in WINE subsystem only if your invoking application is win32 executable too. Otherwise you should have dll sources and try to adapt them for linux compiler of according programming language.

Comment: an example of "adapting" would be great